# You may need an appropriate loader : typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I set up a project with React, webpack, babel, and typescript. 
And I have an error : `You need an appropriate loader.`

This is a part of webpack.dev.config.js

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var parentDir = path.join(__dirname, '../');

module.exports = {

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                },
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loder", "less-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: try to replace the test pattern from `/\.ts|\.tsx$/` to `/\.ts(x)$/`.

Comment: also, make sure you installed the required dependencies: `npm i awesome-typescript-loader babel-preset-es2015 -D`

Comment: @EliranMalka I try your solution , it's the same thing. I reinstall dependancies, but it's the same thing too.

Comment: We need more info from the message. We need to know what file webpack is trying to load.